# Printing pattern

Tags: python

```
# number of rows
rows = 5
k = 2 * rows - 2
for i in range(0, rows):
    # process each column
    for j in range(0, k):
        # print space in pyramid
        print(end=" ")
    k= k-2
    for j in range(0, i + 1):
        # display star
        print("* ", end="")
    print("")
```

I don't understand what this `k= k-2` is for.

Also, what is `k = 2 * rows - 2`, and not simply 8 instead?

Comment: Go through it on paper, step by step, with YOU as the Python interpreter keeping track of the variables.  That should make it clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Hey, I don't understand what is this " k= k-2 " for.

This decreases `k` by `2`, which is necessary after a row has been printed:
`k` is the number of leading space characters to be printed. On the next row, you will need 2 fewer space characters, since there will be one more `*`  (2 characters) to be printed.

Ideally, `k` would have a more telling variable name (like `n_spaces`).

> Also, what is k= 2 * rows - 2, and not simply 8 instead.

This is so that if you choose to modify the `rows` value later on, you don't have to modify `k` too; the script calculates a correct `rows` value for you.
This also communicates the intent better.

Answer (score 1):

The initial answer pretty much covers what I was going to say, but just to expand on why it is wise to stay away from using "hard-coded" values is to accommodate possible flexibility in the user experience when utilizing a program.

Just to embellish that initial great answer, here is an expanded version of the program to highlight what was covered above.

```
def pyramid(num_rows):
    # number of rows
    rows = num_rows
    k = 2 * rows - 2                    # Sets k to the initial number of spaces to print on the first row
    for i in range(0, rows):
        # process each column
        for j in range(0, k):           
            # print space in pyramid
            print(end=" ")              # Print the requested number of spaces without going to a new line
        k= k-2                          # Decrements the number of spaces needed for the subsequent row(s)
        for j in range(0, i + 1):
            # display star
            print("* ", end="")         # Prints the two-character set "* " without going to a new line
        for j in range(0, i):           # Additional loop to print a symmetrical pattern to make it look like a pyramid
            # display star
            print("* ", end="")         # Prints the two-character set "* " without going to a new line
        print("")

pyramid(int(input("Enter the number of rows: ")))
```

Defining the printing of the pyramid (enhanced to produce a symmetrical design) as a function and then calling the function allows for such flexibility.  And not having values hard-coded values allows for a wider use of the program.

Following are a couple of samples at the terminal.

```
craig@Vera:~/Python_Programs/PrintOutput$ python3 Formatted.py 
Enter the number of rows: 5
        * 
      * * * 
    * * * * * 
  * * * * * * * 
* * * * * * * * * 
craig@Vera:~/Python_Programs/PrintOutput$ python3 Formatted.py 
Enter the number of rows: 6
          * 
        * * * 
      * * * * * 
    * * * * * * * 
  * * * * * * * * * 
* * * * * * * * * * *
```

So the additional takeaway here is if there are hard-coded values within a program, there may be consideration for utilizing some formulaic equivalent if there is a need for flexibility in the user experience.